# Netbeans: how to undo clicking "Always run without asking"?

Tags: netbeans

When running a file despite having a compiler error, I accidently marked the checkbox "Always run without asking". I regret this and would like NetBeans to ask me again before running a Java file that has compiler errors. 
How can I do this? This should be simple but I cannot find any way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see from NetBeans bugzilla, this defect was left without reply: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=186776. For example, on my Windows 10 operating system I can manipulate this property using the `C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\java\source\BuildArtifactMapperImpl.properties` file, having now in it `askBeforeRunWithErrors=true`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!